# org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException while start spring boot with OAuth2

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jhipster

I was trying to use spring-boot 1.3.0.RC1 and Oauth2 to build my own rest service app, and copy the same generated code for OAuth2 configuraiton from JHipster, this exception shows:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [hello.OAuth2ServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGL
IB$$d4b42265]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: hello.OAuth2ServerConfiguration$$EnhancerB
ySpringCGLIB$$d4b42265.<init>()
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:85)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.j
ava:1098)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: hello.OAuth2ServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d4b42265.<init>()
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
        ... 24 more
```

my code is:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public OAuth2ServerConfiguration(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    } ...some other code
```

I can't add default constructor, because DataSource is final. Please help me to get the reason, thanks.
I used @postConstruct init(), still not work.

Comment: What version of Spring Boot are you using? Constructor injection for configuration classes is only supported with Spring Boot 1.4 and later (it's a new capability of Spring Framework 4.3)

Comment: Thank you very much, @AndyWilkinson , I was using spring boot 1.3.0.RC1, after upgrade to 1.4.3RELEASE, the exception was gone.